# Prevent http.get from automatically sorting response by key

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am making an API request using http.get

```
this.http.get('https://api.domain.com/test', {headers:headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    console.log('test', data);                      
});
```

The raw json response is:

```
{"1":{"name":"One"},"2":{"name":"Two"},"3":{"name":"Three"},"4":{"name":"Four"},"5":{"name":"Five"}}
```

If I then change the response of the API and set the order of the keys to be 3,2,1,4,5 then console.log still shows the data in the order 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

It seems like either the map or subscribe calls are changing the response and sorting by key. I would like the value of data to be exactly what I get back from my API without being re-sorted. Is this possible?

Comment: In Javascript, object keys are considered "unordered". It is up to the browser to give the keys order, so you shouldn't rely on that order. If you care about order, use an Array

Comment: What @Sidney said!

Comment: I appreciate the help. When you say "use an array", do you mean that I should change my API response format?

Comment: Correct, @Chris

Comment: Much appreciated :-)